Is it possible to use sensor to perform dag when data in postgresql has changed?
I only need to be notified if the data has changed. Can I do this with airflow?
About the problem:
I have a dag that updates warehouse acceptance cost data
@dag(
    schedule='*/5 * * * *',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    tags=['market', 'acceptance_rate']
)
def mp_acceptance_rate():

    @task.external_python(python='/usr/local/airflow/venv_main/bin/python')
    def get_mp_acceptance_rate():
        from src.transform import MpTables
        return MpTables().acceptance_rate()

    @task.external_python(python='/usr/local/airflow/venv_main/bin/python')
    def update_mp_acceptance_rate(data):
        from src.databases.DatabaseWorker import DatabaseWorker
        from src.databases.mp_schema import MpAcceptanceRate

        db = DatabaseWorker()

        with db.session() as session:
            session.upsert(
                MpAcceptanceRate,
                data,
                on_conflict='do_update',
                deletable=True
            )
    _get_mp_acceptance_rate = get_mp_acceptance_rate()
    _get_mp_acceptance_rate >> update_mp_acceptance_rate(_get_mp_acceptance_rate)


mp_acceptance_rate()

I also have a query that returns "suitable" data
SELECT * FROM mp.acceptance_rate mar
WHERE warehouse_id IN (
    SELECT distinct id FROM mp.stock ms
    LEFT JOIN mp.warehouses mw
    ON ms.warehouse_name = mw.name
    WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE
    AND quantity > 0
)
AND coefficient != -1
AND coefficient <= 3
AND box_type_id in (2, 5)
ORDER BY date, warehouse_id

I want the query results to be sent only if the new data differs from the previously sent data. For example, for the first notification, all rows of the query response will be sent (since there is no previous data). Let's say that the next request adds a row (or several rows) compared to the previous request. In this case, a notification should be sent, for example, "Delivery available for {delivery date} to {warehouse 1} with coefficient {coef}." If a row is deleted, a notification should be sent that "delivery for {delivery date} to {warehouse 1} has changed coefficient or is unavailable."
Basically, I want to delegate the task of storing the latest sent data to airflow, and have it immediately compare new and old data and output the difference between them. Of course, this behavior can be done by creating an additional table and doing it as a separate dag, but it seems to me that this is a more resource-intensive method.
